# Is there a gspread cell_list to A1 reference utility function?

Tags: gspread

I'm wondering why there's no obvious cell_list to A1 range utility? Does anyone know if I missed something?

Thanks in advance,
Winton

Comment: What is `cell_list to A1 range utility`?

Comment: cell_list is the data structure holding cells - given the cells internally in the cell_list, create the standard "A1:B2" string that refers to them. The cells internally are named R1C1, R2C2, etc. I could probably write it myself, I was just surprised there didn't seem to be such a function.

Comment: Are you looking for a method in a `Cell` object that returns the A1 notation of that current cell ? If so that can be arranged 

Comment: No, given a cell_list, determined the top left and bottom right cells and then return those as eg   'B2:C4' - no need to add it though, I just wondered if it existed, I can work around this myself.